# Is it possible to get any random big item replicated by request in UFP's Earth?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, economics

> If you want something big, you queue up at an industrial replicator. *(Source: an assertion in [another SFF answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/82810/20774).)*

The implication is that if you want a large material good — yacht? starship? large building? — then you can get it for free, with the only cost being time (that is, the time spent standing in line at an industrial replicator).

**Is there canon support for this?** If no, what is canon evidence for how an average Earthling (in Picard's time) would be able to satisfy a random craving for a large complicated material object/construction?

Answer (score 4):

In "[Explorers](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Explorers_(episode))" of DS9, Sisko built a replica of a Bajoran lightship (i.e. a solar-sail-powered spaceship, complete with artificial gravity) in his spare time as a hobby.

This seems to suggest that large objects — at least the parts needed to build a spaceship in a few weeks — could be very affordably procured.

This was on a space station, not Earth, but I don't see why it should be different.

Comment: Well, he was also the commander of the station...

Comment: Yes, and we know that he basically had unlimited access to an industrial replicator

Comment: Sorry, the question **very specifically** stated "an average Earthling". Sisko is anything but.

Comment: There aren't a lot of average Earthlings in the show. :/ Still, Sisko was acting as a private citizen in that episode, and there is no evidence that he was, say, corruptly channelling resources into his hobbies.