# Are there any large private companies in the Star Trek universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

We know there are small companies on earth like Picard's vineyard and Sisko's (Ben's dad) restaurant, but are there any large private companies that operate within Federation space like say a Procter and Gamble, FedEx, or Boeing size companies?

Private company means private company, not publicly traded stocks, etc. This question has nothing to do with the economic or monitary system or means of exchange. This has to do with any large private company that provides goods or services to others.

Comment: Are you looking for Earth, human, or any and all?

Comment: This is a duplicate.

Comment: The entire economy of the federation is generally dealt with by hand waving and mumbling - can a private citizen get free travel between solar systems?  What if they want to move something massive between solar systems, how do they hire a cargo ship?  Who do they hire the cargo ship off of?  Who built that cargo ship?  If no one gets paid, why is that cargo ship crewed?  Can't be very fulfilling...

Comment: @MartinHandrlica Good point. I limited the question to earth as that would be sufficient to answer the curiosity.

Comment: I assume you don't 'private' in the sense of *not government/military-run*, not *not publicly traded on the stock market*

Comment: If you expand this to the *entire Star Trek universe* (e.g. not just the Federation) this isn't a dupe. There are clearly companies that deal and trade with non-Federation cultures.

Comment: @Richard thanks for the suggestion. I've fine tuned the question and opened up the parameters to include all Federation space.

Comment: I don't think you can class Chateau Picard and Nokia as companies. They're certainly *brands* but we don't have any clue how they're administered.

Comment: Doesn't a company imply seeking currency in exchange for products or services? Do we *know* if Picard's vineyard or any other place of business actually deals with currency in their transactions?

Comment: @Ellesedil - No, we absolutely don't. For all we know, the whole thing is basically a commune.

Comment: @Ellesedil I edited the question... again. The question implies a large company that provides goods and/or services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YES**

There are several mentioned through out the series;

[Dytallix Mining Company](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dytallix_Mining_Company)

[Galactic Mining Company](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Galactic_Mining_Company) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsLKU4YtCSQ) at approx 5.31

[Earth Broadcasting Company](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Earth_Broadcasting_Company)

and an unnamed power company on Bajor
[Power Company](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Power_company)

and several smaller ones including the ones you mentioned in your question

[Quarks Bar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Quark%27s_Bar,_Grill,_Gaming_House_and_Holosuite_Arcade)

[Chateau Picard](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chateau_Picard)

[Sisko's Creole Kitchen](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sisko's_Creole_Kitchen)

Comment: Nice answer. This proves there ARE larger companies operating within the Federation despite all the proclamations to the contrary. Is it suppose to be a quiet little secret none talk about and dismiss out of hand if mentioned?

Comment: @Morgan - There's no special indication that the Earth-based organisations were exchanging *money* for services.

Comment: @Richard no one is talking about "exchanging money". The question is about the existence of larger 'private' businesses. Not the monetary system.

Comment: @Morgan - Fair enough. Can you provide some evidence that the EBD and Galactic Mining companies are actually companies? I don't believe they were named in their respective episodes...

Comment: @Richard that question would be better directed to sfhj_sf as it's her? answer. That's actually why I didn't accept as answered... yet.

Comment: @Richard: For Galactic Mining check the memory-alpha link and for EBC check [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111280/trivia) about half way down the page

Comment: @Morgan: him please

Comment: @sfhq_sf Yes sir :)

Comment: Neither of those are primary sources. Memory Alpha is a fan-wiki and IMDB is wrong more often than it's right.

Comment: @sfhq_sf - I meant you, obviously :-)

Comment: @Richard: Galactic Mining [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsLKU4YtCSQ) at aprox. 5.31

Comment: @sfhq_sf - Yes, but is it a company? I see "Galactic Mining Delta-Vega Station"...

Answer (score 2):

This is a probably duplicate of:
[The fates of corporations in the Star Trek universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82763/the-fates-of-corporations-in-the-star-trek-universe) but that question is somewhat different in focus.

There are two potential examples:

One, in the reboot continuity, there is clear product placement of Nokia phone.   So if you accept that, then you infer that Nokia, or at least some corporation using that brand exists in the 2240s (Kirk is a kid).

[image]

Two,  [Broht & Forrester](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Broht_%26_Forrester) is a holonovel publisher from the *Voyager* episode "Author, Author".   However, it's not really clear if this qualifies as either "large" or as a "company".

[image]

Comment: This is probably the best fit I can find: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82763/the-fates-of-corporations-in-the-star-trek-universe