# Do any Star Trek novels cover life as an ordinary (Earth) person?

Tags: star-trek

Consider that Earth would have aliens and advanced technology, and people evidently have jobs. Do any plots cover what it's like for the average person on Earth?

I don't mean what Starfleet officers do in their private time, but the life on an average non-Starfleet character, with the activities of Starfleet and the Federation in the background.

Comment: In a word, nope.

Comment: @Valorum - Oh, would have been nice though.

Comment: [The Never-ending Sacrifice](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Never-Ending_Sacrifice) covers the everyday lives of Cardassian citizens. The [Rihannsu](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rihannsu) novels address what life is like in the Romulan Empire. [The Vulcan Academy Murders](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Vulcan_Academy_Murders) have quite a lot of background about Vulcan. There isn't (as far as I'm aware) a comparable one for Earth.

Comment: Private companies don't exist. There's no money, remember?

Comment: In Picard, Didn't Seven of Nine kill the alien who harvested Borg parts in a nightclub?

Comment: @Valorum - From [MA](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mot) - By 2399, "Mr. Mot's Hair Emporium", a barbershop bearing his name and featuring his likeness on its signage, was present in Stardust City on Freecloud. (PIC: "Stardust City Rag"), A barbershop is a private business.

Comment: Babyon5’s S5 episode “A View From the Gallery” did this, focusing on an attack on the station through the eyes of maintenance workers Mack & Bo. As Mack and Bo go about their business, we get vignettes of the main characters that Mack and Bo witness. Mack and Bo agree that Sheridan is a great leader, not afraid to get his hands dirty and fight.

Comment: @EmpressSvetlana - Firstly, Picard and Discovery are crapping all over the established canon as if it's going out of fashion and secondly, I believe that was intended to be an 'easter egg' rather than something serious

Comment: Thanks, Richard, for telling it like it is.

Comment: Sisko's father is an "ordinary person" and he runs a restaurant. We don't get a lot of detail on his day-to-day life, but we're shown the fear and panic on Earth near the start of the Dominion war when Founders are reported on Earth. Does that count? (Guess it's not a novel, though...)

Comment: The question of whether there are companies in the Trek universe is dealt with here; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82763/the-fates-of-corporations-in-the-star-trek-universe. As such, I've removed it from your question because I can only see it causing distraction.

Comment: You also get a little information in the TNG episode where Picard goes home after being "healed" from the transformation into a Borg. From there we know at least a liitle bit of information regarding politics (As there is a mayor if I correctly remember), about Science (As there is a research institute which is supposedly non-starfleet as it is suggested to Picard to work there if he leaves starfleet) and of course the Info on his Brother and Nephew, where the former is a vintner and the latter goes to a regular school.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no. There are no Star Trek novels that focus wholly, or even in large part on the life of an ordinary citizen of the Federation *on Earth*.

---

As I mentioned in a comment, there are, however, some stories about ordinary (alien) people set in the Star Trek universe, in particular:

- [The Never-ending Sacrifice](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Never-Ending_Sacrifice) covers the everyday lives of ***Cardassian*** citizens, starting during the Occupation and extending beyond the end of the Dominion War.
- The [Rihannsu](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rihannsu:_The_Bloodwing_Voyages) novels address what life is like in ***the Romulan Empire***, starting with the flight from Vulcan and into the TOS era.
- [The Vulcan Academy Murders](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Vulcan_Academy_Murders) have quite a lot of background about ***Vulcan*** during the TOS era.

But there isn't (as far as I'm aware) a comparable one for Earth.